# Converting TNTUnicode

Tags: delphi, components

I've written an application in Delphi 7 before. I used the TNTUnicode Components for many objects. And now I want to develop it in Delphi XE4.

my problem: Delphi XE4 doesn't support TNTUnicode.

**So, is there any way to convert the TTNTObjects to TObjects?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can convert them to the controls that came with your XE4.

Te easiest way is to open all your dfm files as text and change (for example) `TTntEdit` to `TEdit`. All classes have the TTnt prefix, so it should be easy to find them.

After that, open each form of the project in Delphi.

It'll warn you about controls being of the wrong type, and offer to fix the glitches by updating the form class definition for you.

After removing the TNT units from the `uses` sections, there's a good chance that everything works. Just hit F9 repeatedly, and the Delphi will bring you exactly to the parts that you need to remove :)

You'll probably have to deal with other unicode stuff, but that's most likely not related to the tnt controls.

Comment: Yes, It Worked. I owe you one.

Notice: After removing the TNT units from the uses sections. You had to Change TNT to T in the unit again.

Answer (score 3):

The sole purpose of the TNT components was to add Unicode aware components to versions of Delphi that did not support Unicode natively. Starting with Delphi 2009, Delphi has native support for Unicode.

So, when you port to a Unicode aware version such as XE4, you no longer need TNT components. Simply remove them from your project and use the native components instead. For example, replace `TTntButton` with `TButton`, replace `TTntEdit` with `TEdit` and so on.

If your project is large you'll want to script this. You can probably go a reasonable way using a regex based approach using your favourite scripting language. Make sure you use your revision control system properly to support this endeavour. It is there to save you when your regex changes something that it should not have changed!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to purchase the TMS Unicode Pack (https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/tmsuni.asp).

This has updated the TNT Controls for newer delphi versions, and just aliases the standard delphi classes, so there is no performance penalty in your applications, but saves you from renaming your controls.